# Executing remote shell commands in Java

Tags: java, shell, unix, jsch

I need to execute some remote commands on unix box using java. For that I have used `jsch` but the issue is that I need to collect the output of last command.

i wrote the below piece of code:

```
public static String run(String hostname, String hostPort, String username, String password, String[] commands) throws JSchException, IOException
    {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        // System.out.println("Connected");

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (String s : commands)
        {
            sb.append(s + ';');
        }
        String command = sb.toString();
        channel.setCommand(command);
        channel.connect();

        String msg = null;
        //String output = "";
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //output = output + msg;
            output.append(msg);
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        // System.out.println("DONE");
        return output.toString();
    }
```

In the above code, I am collecting all the command result but i need to collect only result of last command fired.

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: You could parse the output if you know what the last command output looks like; or maybe you could add `> /dev/null` to all commands but the last (not sure if that works, never used Jsch).

Comment: @Octopus - I need to execute all commands but only need to collect result of last command.

Comment: May be you should follow what Jason C said!

Comment: You may fire echo "[[UNIQUEKEY]]" before the last command and then skip everything until you encounter it in your input.

Comment: Why can't you create an executable shell script with the set of steps in the remote machine ?. So that you can give /dev/null redirect in the shell script instead of giving the set of commands in the program itself